# window.addEventListener function is not working at all times

Tags: javascript, html

Through this code i have to hide the dropdown-container when a user clicked outside of the button. And the code works fine initially. But later, it is not responding to the onclick event on button also. sometimes it closes the dropdown if i cliked a button. I have tried with many stackoverflow questions but i didnot get answer. Here is my code. Hope someone could solve this issue.

```
            <div class="button-grp">
                <button class="icon-button" type="button" onclick="menu(event, '1')"><img 
                   src="../../Images/icons/local_library-white-24dp.svg" class="icon"><br>Learning
                 </button>
                <button class="icon-button" type="button"  onclick="menu(event, '2')"><img 
                    src="../../Images/icons/gamepad-white-24dp.svg" class="icon"><br>Tools
                </button>
            </div>
        <div class="sidebar-open">
            <div class="main-options" id="0">
                <button class="options-button" type="button">Academics</button>
                <div class="dropdown-container">
                    <a href="#">Course Details</a>
                    <a href="#">Assignments</a>
                </div>
                <button class="options-button" type="button">Schedule</button>
                <div class="dropdown-container">
                    <a href="#">Exams</a>
                    <a href="#">Classes</a>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
     <div id="mainmenu">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, 
     </div>
```

And my Javascript code is as follows..

```
//function to toggle between clicked buttons and close when double clicked on it.
function menu(evt, id) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".main-options").forEach(function(div) {
    if (div.id === id) {
            // Toggle specified DIV
            if(div.style.display === "block"){
                div.style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("mainmenu").style.marginLeft = "80px";
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
            }else{
                div.style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("mainmenu").style.marginLeft = "230px";
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
            }
    } else {
      // Hide other DIVs
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}
//function to hide the dropdown when clicked outside the button.
window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if (!event.target.matches('.icon-button') ){
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("main-options");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        if (dropdowns[i].style.display === "block") {
        dropdowns[i].style.display ="none";
        document.getElementById("mainmenu").style.marginLeft = "80px";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";

        }
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: Try document.addEventListener

Comment: Yeah, i tried it. but the issue still remains...

Comment: Is the click event firing first of all? Because in the problem description you mentioned it is closing sometimes. May be the condition inside the click event does not match the requirement.

Comment: yeah i have tested that too..beacause the problem arrived only after when i added the window.add...block.

Comment: i think it  is closing when my cursor is placed on the image present in buttont tag. how to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, Exactly, this is because of the if condition you added here. Check whether all the clicks has the target value defined. If not make your if to match the requirement accordingly. By doing so, you can close the dropdown other than the button click.

Comment: Yes, you are right..finally got the solution. And i changed the if statement to..            if(event.target.matches("body")).... as i want to close the sidebar when clicked outside it.

Comment: Awesome.. happy that you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector(".icon-button").forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      ...
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey..thank you for your time.. But i want to close the dropdown container when clicked outside the button. I think i might have listent to click event globally...